# Post picture on Facebook wit Actionscript3 Graph API

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I want to upload a picture from as3 to Facebook, but I'm not finding the right way!
If I post a message, it goes well, but if I load picture nothing happens! The callback function get never called..

```
        var bitmapData:BitmapData=new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height);
        bitmapData.draw(mc);  
        var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);

        var params:Object = { image:bitmap, message:'Test Photo', fileName:'FILE_NAME' };
        Facebook.api("/me/photos", onComplete, params);
```

**EDIT**

It works calling the function above with a mouse or keyboard event! I don't understand why calling it directly still not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem shold be that a user action is required when you try to publish.